# Why this socket data sent only once to the Java server?

Tags: java, sockets

I just want to a programme network game and which needs communication between 
Client Start...
Server Yes...
Client Give me cards...
(Server don't respond on this code and if i have to create always new socket how i will get same address.... localhost is just for test purpose)
Socket running only once I can't understand why????????

i am listeening on server by while true but it gets only one string and don't get any thing on next attempt....

server is just listening and reading

```
package client;     

import java.net.*;            
import java.io.*;                   

public class Client {                        

    Client() {                         
        try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);
        int i=0;
        while(i<100){
            i++;
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);
            pw.println(i);
        }                          
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Client Constructor Exception");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Client client = new Client();
    }
}
```

**Code of Server is..... pleasse help me**

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    Server() {
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2222);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in Server Constructor");
        }
    }

    public void operate() {
        try{
 //           Control control = new Control();
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
               System.out.println(br.readLine());
                //control.recieve(socket, br.readLine());
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in Server operate function");
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.operate();
    }

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
}
```

Output is:

run:
Start

**why it does not run 100 times.....**

Comment: Probably because your server code reads the accepted socket to EOS on the accepting thread instead of starting a new thread per connection, combined with the fact that your client never closes the socket, but until you post the server code it is anybody's guess.

Comment: @Shriram i try to post server just a minute...

Comment: @Shriram I have code of Server also....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In server code you have to move server.accept() outside the loop.
Try this one. It would work. Along with this i tried with instant reply from server.

server code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    Server() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2222);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in Server Constructor");
        }
    }

    public void operate() {
        try {
            // Control control = new Control();
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Server starts listening on "
                        + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

                System.out.println("Server accepts connection.");

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
                pw.println("Hi Client");

//              Thread.sleep(1000);
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("reply sent to client");
                // control.recieve(socket, br.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException /*| InterruptedException*/ e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in Server operate function");
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.operate();
    }

}
```

Client code:

```
package com.java.examples;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    Client() {
        try {
            Socket socket;
             socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);

            // InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            while (true) {
//              socket = new Socket("localhost", 2222);
                System.out.println("Socket - " + socket.getLocalPort());
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
                pw.println("Hi Server");
//              Thread.sleep(2000);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                System.out.println("Waiting for server reply..");
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Got reply from server..");
                // pw.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException/* | /*InterruptedException*/ e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Client Constructor Exception");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client client = new Client();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new socket every time inside the loop, you want to get

```
socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);
```

outside of the infinite loop

Comment: Sorry i want to write loop outside works correctly but inside not how i will copy inside IP address localhost each time

Answer (score 0):

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);  
OutputStream os=null;   
PrintWriter pw=null;     

while(true){                                   
    os = socket.getOutputStream();                   
    pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);                     
    pw.println("Start");                       
}
```

Comment: not working 
just programme is running not recieving any "Start" after once....
But programme remains on hang

Comment: add:
    pw.flush();
after 
    pw.println("start");

Comment: Same situtation its like to stuck socket once on serverSocket and had no effect after once

Answer (score 0):

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);  
OutputStream os=null;   
PrintWriter pw=null;     

while(true){                                   
  os = socket.getOutputStream();                   
  pw = new PrintWriter(os,true);                     
  pw.println("Start");  
  pw.flush();  // to empty the writer buffer                     
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are right listening on the server side ?    can you put your server code ?

Comment: Sir I have put Server code also now in edittt it just println(br.readline);

Comment: On server i just have accept() buffered read line in a while(true)

Comment: you have to put:  socket = serverSocket.accept()   outside the loop